# Send mail with email js with from address of my website title

Tags: node.js, email

I am using emailjs module of nodejs to send email. I am using gmail as my host and I have specified my username and password of my gmail account. It is sending email just fine but in from address it is using my name not my website title. I just want it to use my website tile.
Here is my code:

```
var server  = email.server.connect({
   user:    "myusername", 
   password:"mypassword", 
   host:    "smtp.gmail.com", 
   ssl:     true
});

var message = {
           text:    text_body, 
           from:    title,
           to:      first_name+' '+'<'+email+'>',
           subject: subject,
           attachment: 
           [
               {data: html_body, alternative:true}
           ]
};

server.send(message, function(err, message) { console.log(err || 'Mail sent'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 from: "whatever <your-email-at-google>"
```